# i am using I3D covnNet for activity detection ,how real time video feed is work for detecting human action

Tags: google-colaboratory

i am using I3D covnNet for activity detection ,but here i want to use real time camera feed which recognized human activty from the video and when ever suspicious activity occurs its will record the video and generate an event in a form of alarm and massages

Comment: Too broad, how can we help you?

Comment: Welcome! Which step are you currently having problems with exactly? StackOverflow is no coding service and people here are not going to build your system for you completely. We can help with specific problems though. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about how the site works. Have fun!

Comment: @Adam, i wanna code for live video recording which works in google colab